# How to filter RabbitMQ console listening messages in the application

Tags: log4j, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using spring-amqp with rabbitmq for exchanging of messages in my application.
Once my application get started, i will keep seeing tons of messaging listening logs in my tomcat console. I want to disable. How to do this ?

> 11:01:47.862 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG
>   o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.873
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.888
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.899
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.910
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.921
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.932
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.943
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.954
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.965
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.976
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0 11:01:47.987
>   [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer -
>   Retrieving delivery for Consumer:
>   tags=[{amq.ctag-NzonI8Ja7yjfWuLGLsi4pA=job.queue}], channel=Cached
>   Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/,1), conn:
>   Proxy@64583ac5 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@61e800fb
>   [delegate=amqp://BipUser@10.165.18.29:5672/, localPort= 57216],
>   acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

Below is my log4j configuration.
Even though i have mentioned file appender only, all listeners logs are printing in my application server console.

```
# LOG4J configuration
log4j.rootLogger=WARN

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=C:\\Chandan\\bip.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

Any configuration needs to be added ?

Editing the post :

I have added `-Dlog4j.debug=true` in JAVA_OPTS. . Please find the logs below.

```
    log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader WebappClassLoader
  context: BIP
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418
.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using WebappClassLoader
  context: BIP
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418
 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader WebappClassLoader
  context: BIP
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418
.
log4j: Using URL [file:/C:/Chandan/SoftwareTools/apache-tomcat-8.0.33-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/BIP/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/Chandan/SoftwareTools/apache-tomcat-8.0.33-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/BIP/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[file].
log4j: Level token is [file].
log4j: Category root set to DEBUG
log4j: Finished configuring.
```

The structure of my project is as shown below.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYs4E.png)

Below is my web.xml file config.

```
<context-param>
              <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
              <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/log4j.xml</param-value>
       </context-param>

       <listener>
              <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
       </listener>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably picking up another config file from the classpath rather than using the one you expect.

Run with `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to see which config file is being used.

**EDIT**

Add

```
    <priority value="warn" />
```

or

```
    <priority value="info" />
```

To your `<root/>` logger

Comment: Sorry for asking very basic question. Where to add the line `-Dlog4j.debug=true` in the log file ? What will be the output which comes out of it ?

Comment: It's a JVM system property; you need to add it to the command line when starting tomcat; I think you can do that by setting the JAVA_OPTS environment variable; e.g. `export JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.debug=true` before starting tomcat.

Comment: Hello Gary,
I did some changes and now i am able to see from where the files has been picked. Please have a look at the question
`log4j: Category root set to DEBUG`

I am still able to see lot of listener messages console logs. Any changes in my log4j.properties file ?

Comment: I have set the priority value in log4j. But still listener messages running on my console.Its not working. Please help
`log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[WARN].
log4j: Level token is [WARN].
log4j: Category root set to WARN`

Comment: Configuration worked!! But it is not working in tomcat.It is working in JBoss

Answer (score 0):

The answers above resolves your problem, but if you are using a yaml file to config your project as application.yml, then you can set this config in your application.yml file.

```
logging:
  file: ./log/yourapplication.log 
  pattern:
    console: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} x-tid=%X{x-tid} - %msg%n"
  level:
    root: DEBUG
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener: INFO
```

This configuration has solved many problems and I am using with other log filters like:

```
ch.qos.logback.core: INFO
org.hibernate: INFO
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool: DEBUG
```